# Extract string from one character to another in SQL and remove leading and trail spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the following strings in a SQL table `Cities`:

```
       Info
AUS / Melbourne (AUS) 16th Jul
AUS / Sydney (AUS) 16th Jul
USA/ New York (USA) 16th Jul
```

I am hoping to extract and create a new column so my desired result is:

```
      Info                           City
AUS / Melbourne (AUS) 16th Jul      Melbourne (AUS)
AUS / Sydney (AUS) 16th Jul         Sydney (AUS)
USA / New York (USA) 16th Jul        New York (AUS)
```

I have tried something like:

```
Select 
[Info],
SUBSTRING([Info],CHARINDEX('/ ',[Info])+2,10) as City
from Cities
```

But thats a fixed width of 10 characters, rather I would like the string from the `/` to the closed brackets `)`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks very much

Comment: What's wrong with `TRIM`/`LTRIM`/`RTRIM`?

Comment: I need from the `/` to the `)`. would that work with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a fixed length why not just use `charindex` like you have done but for both delimiters?

```
select Substring([info], CharIndex('/',[info])+2, IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(')',[info]),0)-CharIndex('/',[info])-1,Len([info])))
```

Comment: This is great! yeah I just wasnt sure with the second part. So it works fine when i do it on its own, but i get this error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` when i try and add it as part of a bigger query using: `Substring(a.[info], CharIndex('/',a.[info])+2, CharIndex(')',a.[info])-CharIndex('/',a.[info])-1) as City`. ANy ideas?

Comment: @SOK It works for your sample data, probably you have data that doesn't represent your sample strings eg missing a `)`. I have amended to account for that, how you deal with those ocurrences is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is consistent in structure, you could try this:

`select split_part(split_part([info],'/',2),')',1) || ')' as City`